# how to update by using id in express js and mongoose with parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

[image: This is how my data look from frontend from mongodb]

this is my ejs code  which on clicked on update uses the item.id on url

```html
<div class="header">
    <a href="./viewdatabase">Get Details in json format</a>
    <a href="./getdetails">refresh</a>
</div>
<hr>

<% if(details!=null) { %>
    <table id="bordertable">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Locality</th>
            <% details.forEach((item)=>{ %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= item.name%>`enter code here`
                <a href="/update/<%= item._id %>" >update</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= item.age %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= item.gender%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= item.locality%>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <% }) %>
    </table>
    <% } %>
```

my index.js

```js
    app.get('/update/:id', (req, res) => {    
    var id = req.params.id; 
       res.render('edit.ejs');  
       console.log(req.params.id);
    });

    app.post('/edit',(req, res) => {
     gymApplicant.updateOne({ _id:req.params.id }, {$set: {
        age: req.body.age,
        gender:req.body.gender
     }
     }, function (err, result) {
          if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
         console.log("Post Updated successfully");
         res.render('abc.ejs');
     }
    });
    });
```

which on click on update it redirects to a form to update the age but when i send post request it says not defined because id is out of scope so any idea how to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to insert the `id` in a hidden <input> in edit.ejs so it is sent along the new data to the `/edit` route. Your update route should load the data and render it inside the form btw, so the user can edit the info in place.

Comment: Can you provide a sample code or demo or video or article actually im a newbie

Comment: But you're already doing this in your table view. Load the details of the single user based on the `id`, then insert the data like `<input name="name" value ="<%= item.name %>">`. It's not that complicated.

Comment: i still dont get it  i guess i was not able to present or ask my question clearly so my question is that when clicked on update it redirects to a form where with url /update/idoftheuser   and two text boxes in which i enter my chnages for age and gender and after clicking on submit i want it to do changes to that id but what happens is instead it send to /edit a post request without id to which it going to be updated